# Design bug found on Stack Overflow website

Tags: bug, design

I found a design bug on the Stack Overflow website. Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

The textbox right side is overlapped by the profile container element.

Comment: The top bar looks correct to me, no repro (Firefox / Win10). What's your browser / environment?

Comment: @JohnDvorak Thanks for your support.. I am using Windows 10 OS with Google Chrome Version 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: No repro, looks cool here too. macOS 10.14.5 Chrome 75.0.3770.142 (Official Build) (64-bit)